Login URL /my_app/ did not match /my_app/users/login
I'm getting Login URL /my_app/ did not match /my_app/users/login, even though I've implemented the fix found here (ie. used Router class ):

Cakephp 3 Authentication plugin, login URL did not match
cakephp4 authentication login not working

I'm using the Authentication Plugin version 2.20.2.
Application.php
public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
{
    $login_url = \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/login');
    //dd($login_url) outputs /my_app/users/login

    $service = new AuthenticationService([
        'unauthenticatedRedirect' => $login_url,
        'queryParam' => 'redirect',
    ]);

    //
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Session');
    $service->loadAuthenticator('Authentication.Environment', [
        'loginUrl' => $login_url,
        'fields' => [
            // Choose which environment variables exposed by your
            // authentication provider are used to authenticate
            // in your application.
            'HTTP_SAML_EMAIL',
        ],
    ]);

    //
    $service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Token', [
        'tokenField' => 'email',
        'dataField' => 'HTTP_SAML_EMAIL',
        'resolver' => [
            'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
            'userModel' => 'Users',
            'finder' => 'authenticatedUser',    //check Users table for custom finder
        ],
    ]);
    return $service;
}

Edit #1
Users.login
public function login()
{
    /*
    FAILURE_CREDENTIALS_MISSING - no headers
    FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND - user not found, must be added
    SUCCESS - all good
    */
    
    //get auth status
    $status = $this->Authentication->getResult()->getStatus();

    if($status == 'SUCCESS')    //user found, must update
    {
        //...

        $target = $this->Authentication->getLoginRedirect() ?? \Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller'=>'Users', 'action'=>'workspace']);
        //debug("a:". $target);
        $this->Flash->success(__('You have successfully logged in'));
        return $this->redirect($target);
    }
    elseif($status == 'FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND') //user not found, must add
    {
        //...

        $target = $this->Authentication->getLoginRedirect() ?? \Cake\Routing\Router::url('/users/workspace');
        //debug("b:". $target);
        $this->Flash->success(__('You have successfully logged in'));
        return $this->redirect($target);
    }
    elseif($status == 'FAILURE_CREDENTIALS_MISSING')
    {
        throw new \Cake\Core\Exception\CakeException(__('Authentication error, missing headers. Please contact system administrators.'), 403);
    }
    else
    {
        //THIS IS WHERE WE'RE AT NOW
        debug($this->Authentication->getResult());
        debug($this->request);

        throw new \Cake\Core\Exception\CakeException(__('Uncaught exception during authentication. Please contact system administrators.'), 500);
    }
}

Edit #2
Network trace:

/my_app (301)
/my_app/ (200) (extra slash??)
/my_app/ (500) (expected, $this->Authentication->getResult()->getStatus() is FAILURE_OTHER)

Should I see /my_app/users/login in there? Noting the use of environment headers as authentication mechanism.

The error message can be a bit misleading, it indicates that the URL of the current request is /my_app, meaning you may be sending the login data to the wrong endpoint (misconfigured form for example). Would probably be better if the message said something like "Request URL %s does not match configured login URL %s".

@ndm something, somewhere is redirecting to the root (/my_app) when in fact it should be redirecting to users/login?

That's also a possibility, yes. You'll have to debug the request flow to figure whether that is what's happening.

@ndm Willing to do the work, but have no idea where to start.

In what environment are you authenticating? In a browser (if so, which one)?

In a browser, using Edge (inside my org. better as SSO is available and explains plugin configuration). I also added my Users.login function, in case it might help.

Visit your login form, press F12 to bring up the browser developer tools, open the "Network" tab, check the "Preserve log" and "Disable cache" checkboxes, select the "Fetch/XHR" and "Doc" filters to reduce the noise, submit your login form, and then check the requests and possible redirects (30x Status) in the network tab.

see Edit #2. Noting 301, 200 and 500 (thrown by me due to FAILURE_OTHER).

From where exactly does the authentication request originate? I naively assumed it's a web based form, but I of course don't actually know.

I'm processing SSO headers sent by the web server. In our local, they're set manually in Apache's config file (ex. SetEnv HTTP_SAML_EMAIL "first.last@org.com") to replicate our Azure environments. This is why I chose Authentication.Environment and Authentication.Token.
In the process of moving away from Auth Component (which works) to the Authentication Plugin.

@ndm I think it's my routes! I was mapping the root to Users.login (worked for Auth Component). If I swap out the action, it seems to work throughout.

The issue was my routes.
$routes->scope('/',

    $builder->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'], ['name' => 'app']);

    $builder->fallbacks();
});

I needed to ensure the base route doesn't reflect the same login URL (ie. Users.login).
